# How can I get two same inputs in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an Android game but now testing with input keys.
What I'm trying to do is to get "right" key twice but not sure how.
Here's my code:

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("left"))
    {
        Debug.Log("in the left zone");
        isLeft = true;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
    {
        isRight = true;

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
        {
            isDoubleRight = true;
            isRight = false;
            Debug.Log("in the double right zone");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, same logic would go for the touch in the future. Would it have the same logic with the key input?
Any advice for me please? 
Thanks kindly in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself but not sure if it's right. Hope this helps someone.

```
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("right") && isRight)
    {
        isDoubleRight = true;
        isRight = false;
        Debug.Log("in the double right zone");
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
    {
        isRight = true;
    }
```

Comment: I agree with this approach. But I suggest to also add a test about the time delay (actually, it can pass a long time between the two pressures, but the system will recognize the double pressure also in that case).

Answer (score 0):

## Firstly

Your own answer doesn't detect "double-presses"... it just toggles a variable EVERY SECOND PRESS.

Correcting your code for double-presses would be:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonTest : MonoBehaviour {

    float timeOut = 0.25f;
    float timeLimit; // the latest time a double-press can be made
    string lastButton; // the name of the button last checked

    // an example of using "CheckDouble" is in here
    void Update (){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("right")) CheckDouble("right");
    }

    // The function to check for double-presses of a given button
    bool CheckDouble (string newButton) {
        // if new button press is the same as last, AND recent enough
        if(newButton==lastButton && Time.time<timeLimit )
        {
            timeLimit=Time.time; // expires the double-press
            Debug.Log("Double Press");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            timeLimit = Time.time+timeOut; // set new Limit for double-press
            lastButton = newButton; // for future checks
            Debug.Log("Single Press (so far)");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This will work similar for touches/clicks, but remember:
 Just like this function checks that it was the same BUTTON pressed each time... you will also need to pass it WHAT/WHERE was touched/clicked and compare - to check that someone didn't just single-touch/click on one item, then a single-touch/click a different item very shortly afterwards

---

## Further advice:

To get two same inputs from something (known as overloading)
Systems (like android) sometimes use "Long Presses" (click+hold) rather than double-clicks and I will explain why: 
 Think of a desktop OS 
 1. The "first click" usually just selects something, or inserts a (sometimes imaginary) cursor. 
 2. The "Second click" launches the item, highlights words, toggles the window etc
The point being though, that the "First click" still always happens

*Why?*

because **otherwise** everytime you click ONCE (maybe you are typing on the keyboard, or only want to select one thing) it would have to WAIT to see if you are about to double-click before actioning the single-click. (slow response)

Instead
 Some systems use long-press. As soon as the keypress/touch is RELEASED (onKeyUp/GetKeyUp); if it was within the timeOut, it knows it was a short-press **immediately**, if it is STILL being held after that much time, it performs the long-press action.